# How to add permission for a user on specific page

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have view, edit and delete permissions to a specific page, so I need to get these values:

```
page_id, user_id, edit, view, delete
```

I have a form with page name and 3 checkboxes for each page

```
<div class="container">

<form action="/test" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">

        @foreach( $tmp as $key=>$val )
            <li>
                @if( !isset($val['children']) && empty($var['children']))
                    <b>{{ $val['data']['name'] }}</b>
                @else
                        <b>{{ app()->getLocale() == 'ar' ? $val['data']->ar_name : $val['data']->display_name  }}</b>
                @endif
                @if( isset($val['children']) and !empty($val['children']))
                    <ul>
                        @foreach( $val['children'] as $c=>$child)
                            <li>
                                {{ $child->name }} :

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ $user_id }}">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="{{ $child->name }}">
                                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="arr[]" value="view">View
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="arr[]" value="edit">Edit
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="arr[]" value="delete">Delete
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                @endif

            </li>
        @endforeach
            <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

but when i sent data, i can't get the correct page_id, is there anything else can i do

Comment: are you getting value for $child->name correctly, do a dump inside foreach and check. example: dump($child->name);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding `$child->id`

```
<div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ $user_id }}">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="page_id[{{$child->id}}]" value="{{ $child->id }}">
                                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="view[{{$child->id}}]" value="1">View
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="edit[{{$child->id}}]" value="1">Edit
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="del[{{$child->id}}]" value="1">Delete
                                    </label>
                                </div>
```